# How to set a variable from one condition and use in another in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @someValue INT

SELECT * 
FROM dummytable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT @someValue = somecolumn 
              FROM dummytable2 
              WHERE tableindex = dummytableIndex) 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM dummytable3 
              WHERE somecolumn = @someValue)
  AND SomeDummyFunctionReturnsBool(@someValue) = 1
```

The error is that this statement is not allowed `@someValue = somecolumn`

I am unable to set the value for `@someValue` and use it later.

I tried replacing the error line as `@someValue AS somecolumn` but on printing `@someValue`, it reports `NULL`

Please share if this is supported and the solution to achieve the same.

Comment: you should first declare the variable

Comment: what is the error though

Comment: Completed the code and added more details.

Comment: Use a cursor and loop to get the value for each row in your dummytable.

Comment: The expression(s) in the list of column of a correlated subquery to `EXISTS` aren't actually evaluated and even if `EXISTS` actually retrieved the result of the subquery, that isn't necessarily limited to one row. So your query doesn't make sense at all. To get further advise, edit your question an add the tables' and function's definition (as `CREATE` statements), sample data (as `INSERT` statements) and expected result with that sample data. Also comprehensively explain the logical relation between the input and the output.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to NOT use the variable and rewrite the query as follows for example

```
select * 
  from dummytable
 where exists (select 1 
                 from dummytable3 t3
                 join dummytable2 t2
                   on t3.somecolumn=t2.somecolumn
                where t2.uniqueindex= dummytable.tableindex
               )
```

Comment: I have updated my question for better understanding of the issue.

Comment: @thepace . . . Changing a question after it has been answered is rude -- if it invalidates the answer  -- because such changes can attract downvotes.  This addresses your fundamental question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Apologies if that's the case. I wasn't able to explain the exact issue in the first draft so I ensured to update it with the actual requirement I have. Also, I have given due credit to George in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this for now as a solution. More on lines with George's answer

```
DECLARE @someValue INT
select * from dummytable
where exists 
 (select somecolumn 
  from dummytable2  dt2
  where tableindex=dummytableIndex
     and exists (select * from dummytable3 where somecolumn = dt2.somecolumn 
     and SomeDummyFunctionReturnsBool(@someValue) = 1
   )
```